# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() throws: RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, google-play-services

This GoogleAuthUtil getToken() call:

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(appContext, accountName, scope);
```

occasionally fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare():
ak: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailable
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

So (duh) obviously something is Google's code is trying to create a Handler :) But we are calling getToken() from a standard (non-Looper) thread with all the recommended exception handling per [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) and the documentation explicitly says "*Example of how to use the GoogleAuthUtil in a blocking, non-main thread context*". So e.g. it certainly should not be called on the UI thread.

One thing is ambiguous in the gplay docs: We are passing the Application context to getToken(), but the docs don't say if it expects a specific context e.g. from an Activity. Anyone else have experience one way or the other? I don't see how this could cause the problem but you never know.

The MAIN question: how to recover? Currently we catch the exception and give up, but that does mean we are failing to get a auth for the affected users.

As always guidance from a Googler would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we have figured this out. The RuntimeException is from getErrorDialog() while handling GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException; something about the exception handling was excluding that from the stack trace. This is why the failure is so rare -- only unusual device configs throw that exception.

**WRONG**: like google's documentation example our handler did this:

```
} catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException e) {
    int errorCode = e.getConnectionStatusCode();
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)) {
        Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, resolutionActivity, ...);
```

but that does not work because you cannot call getErrorDialog() on a non-Looper thread.

**FIX**:

```
Activity resolutionActivity = ...;

try {
    String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(appContext, accountName, scope);
    ...
} catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException e) {
    final int errorCode = e.getConnectionStatusCode();
    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)) {
        resolutionActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
                Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, resolutionActivity, ...);
                errorDialog.show();
```

I will update after we have released this and confirmed it is the cause, but it seems likely.

If this is the problem then Google's documentation should be updated as it shows calling getErrorDialog() on a background thread.

---

We shipped the fix above and problem is solved: GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog() should be called on UI thread.